# Receiving errors while using dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I recently added the "Inn" and "Field Trail" sections to this part of my program. This is all that I have changed. It continues to give me a window saying "Syntax Error," and nothing else. No reason, no line number references, nothing.

I have tried to fix the indents, but that helped nothing.

```
rooms = {

        'Tavern' : { 
              'south' : 'Main Road'
            },

        'Main Road' : {
              'north' : 'Tavern',
              'west' : "House",
              'east' : 'Shop',
              'south' : 'Crossroad'
            },

        'House' : {
            'east' : 'Main Road'
            },
        'Shop' : {
            'west' : "Main Road",
            "item" :  'golden_key'
            }
        'Crossroads' : {
            'north' : 'Main Road',
            'west' : 'Inn',
            'east' : 'Field Trail.'
            }
        'Inn' : {
            'east' : 'Crossroads'
            }

     }
```

It continues to give me a window saying "Syntax Error," giving me no information to which line it is on.

Comment: Remove those triple quotes before that last `}`. Effectively, you haven't finished defining the dictionary

Comment: Sorry, that was me trying to add code to the post.

Answer (score 4):

```py
rooms = {

        'Tavern' : { 
              'south' : 'Main Road'
            },

        'Main Road' : {
              'north' : 'Tavern',
              'west' : "House",
              'east' : 'Shop',
              'south' : 'Crossroad'
            },

        'House' : {
            'east' : 'Main Road'
            },
        'Shop' : {
            'west' : "Main Road",
            "item" :  'golden_key'
            }, #<- missing ,
        'Crossroads' : {
            'north' : 'Main Road',
            'west' : 'Inn',
            'east' : 'Field Trail.'
            }, #<- missing ,
        'Inn' : {
            'east' : 'Crossroads'
            }
}

print(rooms)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer is a bit confusing. What am I missing by those closing brackets?

Comment: @Cassinator: You were missing commas, not closing braces.